# Null character when using range-based loop over temporary string?

Tags: c++, string, c++11

When I loop over a temporary `std::string` (rvalue?) using a range-based for loop, there seems to be an extra character, the null terminator `\0`.

When the string is not temporary (lvalue instead?), there is no extra character. Why?

```
    std::map<char, int> m;

    for (char c : "bar") m[c] = 0;

    for (auto [c, f] : m) {
        if (c == '\0') std::cout << "this is a null char, backward slash zero" << std::endl;
        std::cout << c << std::endl; 
    }
```

Output:

```
this is a null char, backward slash zero

a
b
r
```

(note the empty line, where the `\0` is being printed)

Compared to:

```
    std::map<char,int> m;
    
    std::string s = "bar";
    
    for (char c : s) m[c] = 0;    
    
    for (auto [c, f] : m) {
        if (c == '\0') std::cout << "this is a null char, backward slash zero" << std::endl;
        std::cout << c << std::endl; 
    }
```

Output:

```
a
b
r
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `"bar"` is not a `std::string`, but a `char` array (`const char[4]`) containing 4 elements, including the last null character. I.e. [c-style string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal):

> The null character (`'\0'`, `L'\0'`, `char16_t()`, etc) is always appended to the string literal: thus, a string literal `"Hello"` is a `const char[6]` holding the characters `'H'`, `'e'`, `'l'`, `'l'`, `'o'`, and `'\0'`.

For temporary `std::string`s it will work as you expected, i.e. no null character contained.

```
for (char c : std::string{"bar"}) m[c] = 0;
```

Or

```
using namespace std::string_literals;
for (char c : "bar"s) m[c] = 0;
```

BTW as [@HolyBlackCat suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69159188/null-character-when-using-range-based-loop-over-temporary-string#comment122234443_69159236) you can also use [`std::string_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view) (since C++17) which won't include the null-terminated character when constructed from a c-style string literal. E.g.

```
for (char c : std::string_view{"bar"}) m[c] = 0;
```

Or

```
using namespace std::literals;
for (char c : "bar"sv) m[c] = 0;
```

Comment: Can also use `string_view` to avoid heap alloc.